# Where is Gnome #1 in the Stranger Things game?

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

I am nearly at 100% and just need one more gnome! I can’t find gnome #1! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Gnome #1 is behind the house where you start the game. Hoppers house to be exact. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/StrangerThings/comments/74cbz5/stranger_things_the_game_discussion/)